# SQL replace/ remove multiple date and time stamp from any part of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, replace

I have a nvarchar field that contains multiple date & time stamps and various text. The date and time can be at any position in the field.

I want to select only the text from the field. I have tried with REPLACE and PATINDEX to no avail.

Please can anyone share how i would write my select on this example notes field which contains this string:

ADMIN1 21/04/2017 02:01:01 This student is here and trying to gain a masters. 
ITSYS2 09/05/2017 03:51:04 60 APL Credits on xout

[image]

Comment: Are there no other delimiters you can parse through? Tabs or new lines?

Comment: I had thought to split the string at each space, but there isn't a real pattern to how the user enters the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will exclude dates and times from the note_detail.  This is an in-line approach, but just about any split/parse function will do the trick as well.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table(studend_id int,note_detail varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'CHIDLOL 21/04/2017  02:01:01 '+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'This studend is here and trying to gain a masters.  THOMASXC 09/05/2014 03:54:04 60 APL Credon on xout')

Select A.studend_id
      ,new_note_detail = B.S
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select S = Stuff((Select ' ' +RetVal 
                  From (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(replace(A.note_detail,char(13),' '),char(10),' '),' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) B1
                  Where RetVal not like '%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]%'
                    and RetVal not like '%[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9]%'
                  Order by RetSeq
                  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
studend_id  new_note_detail
1           CHIDLOL This studend is here and trying to gain a masters. THOMASXC 60 APL Credon on xout
```

> **Edit - Option 2 with a Parse Function**

```
Select A.studend_id
      ,new_note_detail = B.S
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select S = Stuff((Select ' ' +RetVal 
                  From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](replace(replace(A.note_detail,char(13),' '),char(10),' '),' ') B1
                  Where RetVal not like '%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]%'
                    and RetVal not like '%[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9]%'
                  Order by RetSeq
                  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
             ) B
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

Comment: hi John, thank you for you reply, when i apply this code the date and time stamps are replaced with these characters    &#x0D;&#x0D;

Comment: @clare those are CRLFs .  Do you want the line feeds or do you want them stripped out?

Comment: Hi John yes please I would like the CRLF removed too

Comment: @clare Updated both options.

Comment: This has worked great. I used the inline solution thanks.

Comment: @clare Happy it helped